# Angular page jumps to top when clicking anywhere at the bottom

Tags: html, angular

I have a page with an Ngfor, when I click anywhere at the bottom of the page, it jumps to the top. When trying to click on a button at the bottom, the button's action never occurs and it also jumps to the top

This doesn't happen before the NgFor fills the page with elements; only when the height of the page has increased following the ngFor's completion.

Comment: Please present a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and tell us what you tried to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening the file dialog causes this behavior. There is no fix.